# Get combobox set value as string

Tags: c#, combobox

Found several ways to do so, but none of them works for me..
I have a combobox with variable number of options (taken from dynamic xml file). For next, I need to know what the user choosed, and I cant find out how to do it. This is one of ways I found and tried:

```
string myString = myCombobox.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

At least I dont get an error, but when I try to show that string, it does nothing.

Comment: Perhaps if you show us your code where you add the items to your `ComboBox` and what the results of your debugging are, we can give you an answer that works for you.

Comment: `ComboBox rwy = new ComboBox();
                rwy.Location = new Point(330, 15);
                rwy.Size = new Size(60, 13);
                rwy.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
                string rwyNumber = null;
                foreach (XmlNode runway in runways)
                {
                    rwyNumber = runway.Attributes.GetNamedItem("name").Value;
                    rwy.Items.Add(rwyNumber);
                }`
The combobox works fine, I need to get its selected value for filtering offered options in a next combobox just next to it.

Answer (score 6):

Had a similar problem, try this:

```
string myString = ((ComboBoxItem)myCombobox.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
```

It works for me!

Just try to understand seeing `myCombobox` design.

Answer (score 5):

```
myCombobox.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 3):

```
string myString = myCombobox.Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `mycombobox.SelectedItem.ToString();` Instead of the `SelectedValue`

Answer (score 0):

Try with `myCombobox.SelectedValue.Value.ToString()` or `myCombobox.SelectedValue.Text.ToString()`. Anyway, this question is too low quality for this forum. You need to do some research before asking. That's why I'm voting down you.

Comment: I think the question is legit.

Comment: And `.Text` is already returns a `String` so why are you calling `.ToString()` ?

Comment: I did research, I have spent about an hour googling this up, I also found some questions just like this one on this forum, but as I said, I couldnt get any of the solutions work here, thats why i created a new one.

Comment: First result searching for "asp combobox": http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/ajax-control-toolkit/combobox/how-do-i-use-the-combobox-control-cs

Answer (score 0):

try myCombobox.SelectedItem.ToString();

it will work if you are adding items to the combobox using this way:

```
  comboBox1.Items.Add("Item");
```

e.g.

```
        myComboBox.Items.Add("Item1");
        myComboBox.Items.Add("Item2");
        myComboBox.Items.Add("Item3");

        myComboBox.SelectedIndex = 1; //force change selection
        Console.WriteLine(myComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString()); //will output Item2
```

Comment: Just to be sure how to use this, is this correct? When i try to debug this, it says NullReferenceException was unhandled.
Label.Text = myCombobox.SelectedItem.ToString();

(of course the label is defined before, and it works when I enter just some text").. I  just need to get the value as a string I can work with, and displaying it is just a way I test if I am getting the value correctly.

Comment: Can you write how you're adding elements to myCombobox?

Comment: here it is:
`
foreach (XmlNode runway in runways)
                {
                    rwyNumber = runway.Attributes.GetNamedItem("name").Value;
                    rwy.Items.Add(rwyNumber);
                }
`

Comment: myCombobox was a name just in the question to simplify it, the combobox name is "rwy". To clarify the names - it is just choosing a runway at an airport..

Comment: Looks quite straightforward. My suggest is to ensure that you're using right combobox, and try to output its value to console or you can upload code somewhere so I will be able to glance at it

Comment: Here is the whole visualstudio project, thanks for your help.
https://rapidshare.com/files/547813566/WindowsFormsApplication2.rar

Comment: Ok, as far as I understood your sources you need to read selected item in ssr_Click method. Here solution: add this line ssr.Tag = rwy; immediatelly after you've created ssr button. and these two lines at the beginning of ssr_Click method                    ComboBox rwy = (ComboBox)((Button)sender).Tag;
string selectedText = rwy.Text;

Comment: The ssr_Click has nothing to do with this combobox. Let me explain a bit more:
from the xml i download a list of available runways and i offer them in the rwy combobox. User picks one, I need to know which one he picked (thats the thing I dont know how to do), save it into string and then I am going to make some "if" with this string in the next combobox called sidRoute. In sidRoute would be a huge amout of options, so I will need to filter only those which contain the runway picked in the previous combobox.

Comment: So you need to add rwy.SelectedIndexChanged handler and put this line inside it string text = ((ComboBox)sender).Text;

Comment: Well, now it seems it saves the value to the text string :)) Thanks a lot. One more thing - now that down in the code i have a method rwy_SelectedIndexChanged and inside it I get the value into a string variable, how can I get the value back from where i called the method? I tried setting its return type to string, so it was "public string SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) and on the end I added line "return text;" but it wont work, I just guess I cant do that. Any way to get the value back there so I can use it in sidRoute combobox?
Anyway, thanks a lot!!

Comment: yes, this is impossible to return something from the event delegate and you haven't to do this at all. You're using dynamic creating of ui controls in a bad way. I'd rather use wpf listbox with custom item style (which will contain all elements) and some datacontext bounded to it. You can read more about listbox here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/listbox-in-wpf/